# IIdentity when running a containerized application?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-security

So I'm relatively new to containers in the cloud.

I've done some proof of concepting with **Azure Container Instances** (example : https://xpirit.com/2017/11/12/containers-as-a-service-in-azure/), and **AKS** (example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal)

Coming from an On-Premise world....what is getting lost in the examples is the idea of IIDentity.

For example, if I have a Windows 2012 Server, running a Windows-Service or an IIS hosted application, there is idea of IIDentity.  Windows Service, it would be the user tied to running the Windows Service.....(set either by code, or by properties in Control-Panel/Services).  With IIS, it is the use running the App-Pool.

So separately I've read about

Service Identity's and even Managed Service Identity.
(example : https://anthonychu.ca/post/secrets-aspnet-core-key-vault-msi/ )

Here is what is alluding me.

How do I set the "IIdentity" when running

1. A dotnetcore app *** running in "Azure Container Instances"
2. A java app ***** running in "Azure Container Instances"
3. A dotnetcore app *** running in "AKS"
4. A java app ***** running in "AKS"

or am I barking up the wrong tree?

==================

Docker "images" below

- *** "FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0"
- ***** "from java:8"

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm thinking about it now is "A managed-service-identity (MSI) is applied on top of the VM that is running the container".

This article talks about it:

https://banzaicloud.com/blog/azure-msi-role/

The key here is that...once a kubernetes type VM is created, you can manually go in and turn-on the Managed-Service-Identity capability.

Go to the VM (that kubernetes created......there may be more than 1 VM).......

Click on the "Configuration" tab.

BEFORE I do this magic turn-on.....the text reads:

```
"Managed Service Identity"
"Register with Azure Activity Directory"
and a bug NO/YES push button.
```

AFTER I turn this magic on, it'll read:

```
Just-in-time access
To improve security, enable a just-in-time access policy.
Upgrade your Azure Security Center subscription to the standard tier
```

Now this kinda enables the ability to use Managed Service Identity.

Then you gotta map some Managed Service Identity to the actual VM.

I'm still working on this.........so I'll try to update this answer as I learn more.

But the theory is that once the MSI is "applied onto the VM", the VM (application code) will be able to get a Token, as seen in the code below.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
```

Here is a bigger sample code size......(copied and pasted from chu.ca site link above) (but just in case that link does down)

```
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication package.


public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
        {
            var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
            {
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT");
```

I have not yet seen how to give the MSI "rights to the read the KeyVault" yet......that is still in progress.